# iOS swift ui preview crashes with multiple modules

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am facing a problem, where I have a project using UIKit, with multiple modules in it.
When adding a swiftUI view, if it is in the main module, it displays it okay, when trying to add it to another module, it crashes with the following error.

> XCPreviewAgent may have crashed. Check ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for any crash logs from your application.
> ==================================

> | RemoteHumanReadableError |
> | --- |
> | LoadingError: failed to load library at path "/Users/andrew.maher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-eppsdymsecoxglarlduaphfzpwiv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/QA/Products/Debug (QA)-iphonesimulator/ProjectC.framework/ProjectC": Optional(dlopen(/Users/andrew.maher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-eppsdymsecoxglarlduaphfzpwiv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/QA/Products/Debug (QA)-iphonesimulator/ProjectC.framework/ProjectC, 0x0000): tried: '/Users/andrew.maher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-eppsdymsecoxglarlduaphfzpwiv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/QA/Products/Debug (QA)-iphonesimulator/ProjectC.framework/ProjectC' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Users/andrew.maher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-eppsdymsecoxglarlduaphfzpwiv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/QA/Products/Debug (QA)-iphonesimulator/ProjectC.framework/ProjectC' (errno=2), '/Users/andrew.maher/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-eppsdymsecoxglarlduaphfzpwiv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/QA/Products/Debug (QA)-iphonesimulator/ProjectC.framework/ProjectC' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/ProjectC.framework/ProjectC' (errno=2)) |
> |  |
> | ================================== |
> |  |
> |  |

[image]

Comment: hint: arm64 is real phone architecture, x86_64 is simulator on Mac Intel. Check your module build arch

Comment: Module build architecture is 'Standard Architectures (arm64)'

Comment: Did you try an infamous "Open with Rosetta" workaround? (i.e.: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861#:~:text=For%20apps%20labeled%20Application%20(Universal,updated%20to%20support%20Apple%20silicon.)

Comment: Yes, Already opening it with rosetta